# Random hex color in hex C#

Tags: c#, colors, hex

I have a code which contains colors in hex, and I would like to make this color randomly

```
 PetData = "1 24 #fff";
```

How could I make it?

Comment: Any preferences on distribution? A uniform distribution of RGB colors is not uniform in HSV space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.Format` and use the hex format for the arguments

```
var random = new Random();
var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
```

this color variable gives you the hexadecimal code for random color.

If you want in RGB Format also refer this Link : [Random Hex Color in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342765/problem-in-generating-random-colors-asp-net-and-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you! i've done this :
 var random = new Random();
  var color = String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x1000000));
Random randNum = new Random();                                    var race = randNum.Next(25); 
int typeanimal = 1;
                                                            Session.GetBobbaz().PetData =  typeanimal, race, color;

But it seems the syntax is not right when i declare the PetData, i'm a beginner :s

Comment: Done, about the syntax of 
PetData = typeanimal, race, color; what is wrong please ?

Comment: @user3640047 Can you please post your code where exactly you declare the PetData ?

Comment: Yes, I am not sure about typeanimal syntax, I've put int typeanimal = 1; but it is not really necessary to use it if I can put PetData = 1, race, color ///////
PetData = "1 24 #fff"; This code above was running fine, i juste want to replace 24 and #fff by randoms vars in fact, but my syntax have something wrong I guess...

Comment: @user3640047 OK. you are using int typeanimal = 1; Try with var typeanimal = 1; OR you can also try with the RGB format from the link i referred.

Comment: same errors using int or var.
Erreur 8 =>
Only a subpoena, call, increment, decrement, expectation and new object expressions can be used as instruction (typeanimal race and color are underlined only in the "PetData =" not in the declaration of those)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a Guid.

A GUID is a 128-bit value consisting of one group of 8 hexadecimal digits, followed by three groups of 4 hexadecimal digits each, followed by one group of 12 hexadecimal digits.

Generate a new Guid() and parse out any six digits (excluding dashes):

```
public string GetRandomHexColor()
{
    var result = "#" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 6);
    return result;
}
```